# How to crawl Facebook event pages using PHP DOM?

Tags: php, facebook, dom

I want to create a crawler which can crawl all the events listed on Facebook events. I have a facebook link from where I can access all the pages.
I just want to know, when I use regex(later I'll use DOM) to crawl any specific event page, my crawler fetches data from it's homepage(login page).
How can I access all the facebook events page?

I had roughly written this code to fetch page title:  `/<title.+?>(.+)<\/title>/` . It gives the output: "Update your browser | Facebook"

I think using Facebook's FQL is a better way to connect with Facebook and extract data. Can anyone please let me know the process to use FQL and SDK?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Actually I haven't used FQL and SDK of Facebook. I simply tried using a piece of code to extract page title of any any event. I have added that code in my question!

Comment: Have you tried the [official resources](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)? Take a look at the docs for the relevant SDK you want to use (in the left sidebar).

Comment: Yeah, I read that resource. Now just let me know how to initialize SDK, I have my app id and secret.

Comment: If you're asking how to initialize the sdk you haven't read it fully.

Comment: No, I did it. That time composer setup asked to check php.exe, what I couldn't understand. Thanks for your help. If I need any other help, I'll let you know.